# Fastest way to split a list into a list of lists based on another list of lists

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, partitioning

Say I have a list that contains 5 unique integers in the range of 0 to 9.

```
import random
lst = random.sample(range(10), 5)
```

I also have a list of lists, which is obtained by splitting integers from 0 to 19 into 6 groups:

```
partitions = [[8, 12], [2, 4, 16, 19], [1, 6, 7, 13, 14, 17], [3, 15, 18], [5, 9, 10, 11], [0]]
```

Now I want to split `lst` based on the reference `partitions`.
For example, if I have

```
lst = [0, 1, 6, 8, 9]
```

I expect the output to be a list of lists like this:

```
res = [[0], [1, 6], [8], [9]]
```

I want the algorithm to be as fast as possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which is the constant factor here? Do you need to do the job for several `lst` based on the same `partitions`, or vice versa, or is each task working with different values for both?

Comment: Of course the ```partitions``` is the constant factor. I don't understand how is this not clear in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res=[]

for sublist in partitions: # go through all sublists in partitions
    match = [i for i in lst if i in sublist] # find matching numbers in sublist and lst
    if match: # if it is empty don't append it to res
        res.append(match)
# at this point res is [[8], [1, 6], [9], [0]]                                                                                                         
print(sorted(res)) # use sorted to get desired output
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the fastest algorithm but it works

```
import random
lst = random.sample(range(10), 5)
partitions = [[8, 12], [2, 4, 16, 19], [1, 6, 7, 13, 14, 17], [3, 15, 18], [5, 9, 10, 11], [0]]
sequence = []
result = []

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(len(partitions)):
        if lst[i] in partitions[j]:
            if j in sequence:
                where = sequence.index(j)
                result[where] += [lst[i]]
            else:
                result += [[lst[i]]]
                sequence += [j]
            break
print(result)
```